# javascript getter Id of object collection in Class

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do you access the id of an element that's in a collection in a class using the getter and setter methods on click event for the buttons in my example code below

```js
class MyClass {
  #index;
  
  constructor(selector) {
    this.els = document.querySelectorAll('button');
    this.#init(this);
  }
  
  get Id() {
    return this.els[this.#index].getAttribute('id');
  }
  
  #init(self) {
    Array.from(this.els).forEach((el, index) => {
      self.#index = index;
      self.#bind(el, 'click', self.#onclick, self, index);
    });
  }
  
  #bind(el, event, func, self, index) {
    el.addEventListener(event, func.bind(self, index));
  }
  
  #onclick(...args) {
    console.log(this.Id);
  }

}

new MyClass();
```

```html
<button id="button1">Button 1</button>
<button id="button2">Button 2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with the code:

- You have a `self` variable in `#init` that is a copy of `this`. Every time you set a value for `#self.index` you are overwriting the previous value held at `#this.index`. In other words, `#this.index` only has the last value you set at `#init`.
- Related to that, the `#onclick` function has no information about which button has been pressed. It gets information on the last button that was processed by `#init`.

If you only need to pass the button that has been clicked to `#onclick`, you do not need to keep track of indexes with getters or setters. The key is to pass a variable to `#onclick` (`fc` in the code):

```js
class MyClass {
  #index;
  
  constructor(selector) {
    this.els = document.querySelectorAll('button');
    this.#init();
  }
  
  #init() {
    const self = this;
    Array.from(this.els).forEach((el, index) => {
      const fc = function(){self.#onclick(el)};
      self.#bind(el, 'click', fc, self, index);
    });
  }
  
  #bind(el, event, func, self, index) {
    el.addEventListener(event, func.bind(self, index));
  }
  
  #onclick(...args) {
    const b = arguments[0];
    console.log(b.getAttribute('id'));
  }

}

new MyClass();
```

```html
<button id="button1">Button 1</button>
<button id="button2">Button 2</button>
```